# How to change the name of generated class in vertx 3.4.2

Tags: java, vert.x

With Vertx, I define SomeService with annotation @VertxGen
@ProxyGen. Vertx CodeGen will generate EBProxy and ProxyHandler and also the SomeService Interface, SomeService Class.

I know the Vertx Codegen will generate the code by the *.templ and codegen in the Vertx.

If i just wanna to change the Generated Class's name , is there some better way to do that, like 'inherit' form vertx templ? or i have to write my own templ to make it? Thanks.